# neo4j console fails

Tags: linux, console, neo4j

Hi I moved an install of neo4j onto my linux server using scp.  It is currently residing in /tmp/neo4j-community-1.9.M04/

Tried starting it

```
[afrieden@had03 neo4j-community-1.9.M04]$ ./bin/neo4j start
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [3441]... waiting for server to be ready... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

But it failed.  So I ran the console.

```
[afrieden@had03 neo4j-community-1.9.M04]$ ./bin/neo4j console
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
3/14/13 9:17:00 AM org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
2013-03-14 13:17:02.186+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Startup failed
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@40bc5596' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:494) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:244) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:88) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:82) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:110) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59) [neo4j-server-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70) [neo4j-server-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:277) [neo4j-server-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:157) [neo4j-server-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86) [neo4j-server-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49) [neo4j-server-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@19de0b5e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:494) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:128) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:488) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/tmp/neo4j-community-1.9.M04/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:173) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(CommonAbstractStore.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractDynamicStore.<init>(AbstractDynamicStore.java:72) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.DynamicStringStore.<init>(DynamicStringStore.java:49) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newDynamicStringStore(StoreFactory.java:120) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newRelationshipTypeStore(StoreFactory.java:126) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.attemptNewNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:103) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:92) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:240) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:488) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M04.jar:1.9.M04]
... 15 common frames omitted
3/14/13 9:17:02 AM org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper SEVERE: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@40bc5596' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:257)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:88)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:82)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:110)
at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:277)
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:157)
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@40bc5596' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:494)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:244)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@19de0b5e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:494)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:128)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:488)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/tmp/neo4j-community-1.9.M04/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:173)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(CommonAbstractStore.java:115)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractDynamicStore.<init>(AbstractDynamicStore.java:72)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.DynamicStringStore.<init>(DynamicStringStore.java:49)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newDynamicStringStore(StoreFactory.java:120)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newRelationshipTypeStore(StoreFactory.java:126)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.attemptNewNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:103)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:92)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:240)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:488)
... 15 more
3/14/13 9:17:02 AM org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

And got all these errors.  Not sure what to make of them.  Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some other process connected to the same neo4j db?

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/tmp/neo4j-community-1.9.M04/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.*