# grails neo4j plugin getting bean error

Tags: grails, neo4j

Getting this error when doing run-app on my grails project

```
Error 2013-03-26 12:27:06,100 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
Message: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
Line | Method
->> 117 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
```

---

```
|   303 | innerRun               in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
^   680 | run                    in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
->> 117 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   303 | innerRun               in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
^   680 | run                    in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
->> 117 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   303 | innerRun               in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
^   680 | run                    in java.lang.Thread

Caused by IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
->> 178 | checkStorage           in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   119 | <init>                 in     ''
|    71 | <init> . . . . . . . . in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractDynamicStore
|    47 | <init>                 in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.DynamicStringStore
|   111 | newDynamicStringStore  in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory
|   117 | newRelationshipTypeStore in     ''
|    93 | attemptNewNeoStore . . in     ''
|    82 | newNeoStore            in     ''
|   232 | <init> . . . . . . . . in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource
|   457 | create                 in org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase
|   227 | run . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    79 | <init>                 in org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
|    70 | <init> . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   117 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
|   303 | innerRun . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run                    in     ''
^   680 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the same answer as [neo4j console fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415303/neo4j-console-fails)

Your exception contains-

> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store
>   [/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names],
>   this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the
>   same store.

which is self-explanatory.

Comment: Oops didn't see it in the first half of the line